# Uploading 100,000 binary files as attachments to Case record - best approach

Tags: data-loader, attachment, data, bulk-api, performance

I want to upload files (.doc, .pdf) from external system to the attachments of Case record.

There are two approaches I have found from Salesforce Help.

> 1) [Uploading Attachments](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=loader_attachments.htm&language=en_US) by data loader where I can upload attachments with or without Bulk Api option.
>
> 2) [Loading Binary Attachments](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/binary_intro.htm) where I can upload attachments with Bulk Api

My question is, if some cases attachment size is more than 10MB per file and I need to upload more that 100,000 records as Case attachments then what will be best option I will choose?

Comment: Two favorites yet no upvotes. That is very strange behavior indeed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest you to go with data loader using SOAP API, which is by default (not Bulk API).

**Why?**

1. You do not need to write any code to use Data loader
2. It is tested solution, so no bugs
3. With SOAP API you will need around 500+ API (100000 records / 200 batch size = 500 API required) which is not too much (we have 100k API limit per 24 HRS for enterprise org).
4. Also depending on your data and schema you may face locking issue with Bulk API.
5. Bulk API does not allow zip file size more than 10 MB Ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_concepts_limits.htm

Comment: I will investigate and let you know

Comment: Sure, Testing in sandbox before actual data load in production is best practice!

Comment: your approach seems to be correct and we are doing some testing in sandbox.

Comment: in the csv file how many records can we have and what is the file size limit of csv file?

Comment: With SOAP API there is no limit as such on rows or file size. As your csv file will be on local pc always and only 200 records (whatever batch side you define) will be posted with SOAP api.

Comment: You will need multiple API calls and there is limit on total number of API call. check point # 3 above.

Comment: I have posted one more question, can you please suggest, http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139630/dataloader-csv-file-size-or-record-count-limit