# Dataloader csv file size or record count limit?

Tags: data-loader, attachment, csv

I want to upload attachments into `Case` record through `Dataloader`. To upload attachments I need to define only these 4 columns: ParentId, Name, Description and Body.

> 1. What is the limit of csv file size or record count per .csv file.
> 2. Can I upload the file which are in network drive (not in local machine) specifying the file path.

Note: I am not using CLI for dataloader and not going for Bulk API option.

Comment: There's no limit aside from the storage limit Salesforce itself imposes. But it simply calculates 2KB per record, so I think you need 30M records before it becomes an issue. (I think the limit is 60GB...)

Comment: Can you please share any document reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First part is already answer with documentation link so I am addressing only 2nd question.*

Yes we can refer file stored on network drive using data loader. The only think we need to consider is delay involved for reading file from network drive.  If the delay is significant then your migration process will be slow. But technically its possible to do so.

Answer (score 3):

I can't flag this question as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359720/how-many-records-can-be-loaded-into-salesforce-using-apex-data-loader-in-one-go), but this question has already been asked on [Stack Overflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com). So I'll just quote the **[Data Loader Guide](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/20/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_data_loader.pdf)** and [@eyescream](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/799/eyescream) (emphasis mine):

> #### Use Data Loader when:
>
> - You need to load 50,000 to 5,000,000 records. Data Loader is supported for loads of up to 5 million records. **If you need to load more than 5 million records, we recommend you work with a Salesforce partner or visit the App Exchange for a suitable partner product.**

Comment: My question is bit different, I have gone through dataloader guide.

Comment: @SantanuBoral But the answer is the same. Up to 5M records you're definitely good. After that, you may want to consider a different tool or break up your csv.

Comment: Can I breakup the csv file as 50,000 records per file?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you. But there's also no need to go to that trouble for less than 5 million records.

Comment: So can I upload data from single csv file with 1 millon data?

Comment: According to the guide, that is well within the limits of what Data Loader can handle.